# Draft10 with WSS

Tags: netty

I'm trying to run Netty Draft10 latest example on top of SSL (WSS)

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/server

I'm using the following port configuration:

Port: 80:   Apache non ssl
Port: 443:  Apache ssl
Port: 8080: Tomcat
Port: 8877: Netty Web non SS
Port: 9977: Netty SSL

But when I embedd the SSL handler code

```
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {

    //TODO - Tamir - Add support for Wss
    // Get the SslHandler in the current pipeline.
    // We added it in SecureChatPipelineFactory.
    final SslHandler sslHandler = ctx.getPipeline().get(SslHandler.class);

    // Get notified when SSL handshake is done.
    ChannelFuture handshakeFuture = sslHandler.handshake();
    handshakeFuture.addListener(new Greeter(sslHandler));
}
```

into the WebSocketServerHandler class I get an error message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text 
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:95) 
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:68) 
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:81) 
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:198) 
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:107) 
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:470) 
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:443) 
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:275) 
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:262) 
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:340) 
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:271) 
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:191) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: ?_?_?__
```

This is my pipeline code

```
SSLEngine engine =
        SecureChatSslContextFactory.getServerContext().createSSLEngine();
    engine.setUseClientMode(false);

    pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));

    // On top of the SSL handler, add the text line codec.
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

    // and then business logic.
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new WebSocketServerHandler());
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Tamir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just uploaded a working example of web sockets with SSL which I've merged with master.

See pull request: https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/53.

The new code is in src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/sslserver

Please read package-info.java for setup instructions.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please mark this as answered so our filter don't keep show this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I came across this issue my self I thought it might be worth mentioning:

Under some circumstances, The parsing of initialLine parameter  HttpRequestDecoder  is wrong.
this might happen if you don't add a path to the URI , i.e you try ws://localhost:8080 without adding /websocket to the URL.

```
return new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.valueOf(initialLine[2]),
                HttpMethod.valueOf(initialLine[0]), initialLine[1]);
```

The HTTP version field is supposed to be in initialLine[2] but instead it appears in initialLine[1].